# MYSQL JOIN and get full row based on MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, max

Really tried to search for a solution to this, but I can't get it to work.
I have 2 tables in Mysql `event_parties` and `events`.

```
event_parties:
g_event_id   agent_id
----------   --------
2917         2
2918         2
2919         2
3067         3
3078         3

events:
g_event_id   event_id   event_time
----------   --------   ----------
2917         29         2016-10-19 15:24:25
2918         31         2016-10-19 15:24:28
2919         30         2016-10-19 15:29:46
3067         29         2016-10-20 15:33:46
3078         30         2016-10-21 15:29:46
```

I need an JOIN between these two tables with `g_event_id` as the `ID.`
I need all fields in table `events` and I need the row with highest `g_event_id` or with highest `event_time`.

Like this:

```
agent_id   g_event_id   event_id   event_time
--------   ----------   --------   ----------
2          2919         30         2016-10-19 15:29:46
3          3078         30         2016-10-21 15:29:46
```

Been struggling with this for several days :(

/ Kristian

Comment: *for several days* really

Comment: Can there be several entries in `event_parties` for one `g_event_id`? If so, which agent_id to show in this case? And can there be two records in `events`, one with a higher `g_event_id` and the other with a higher  `event_time`? If so, which of the two would you want to show?

Comment: No in table event_parties the g_event_id is uniq.

Comment: updated my answer to match "highest per agent_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just the one highest:
`ORDER BY g_event_id DESC, event_time DESC LIMIT 1`

UPDATE:

for highest per something, you need a double join.
first have all in one table, and then join in later,
and the one row that don't have a later evetn, is the latests event.

for g_event_id as definition of later

```
SELECT event_parties.agent_id, event_parties.g_event_id, event_id, event_time
FROM event_parties
INNER JOIN events USING (g_event_id)
LEFT JOIN event_parties AS later_event
   ON (later_event.agent_id = event_parties.agent_id 
      AND later_event.g_event_id > event_parties.g_event_id)
WHERE later_event.g_event_id IS NULL
GROUP BY event_parties.agent_id
```

Comment: Works!
Problem is though that its really slow, takes 32 sec to get the data.

Comment: Works! Problem is though that its really slow, takes 32 sec to get the data. Is their any way to make the code faster? Each table contain about 4000 rows.

Comment: sounds like missing indexes, prefix "DESCRIBE" before the SELECT to see what indexes its using, i guessing on a "ALTER TBALE event_parties ADD INDEX (agent_id, g_event_id)" would make it less then a secound

Comment: Did try with DESCRIBE in front of Select, the outcome:

Comment: Did try with DESCRIBE in front of Select, the outcome:  http://internal.kamoda.se/images/keys.png  If i read the documentation on the INDEXES for the tables this is what i got: "event_parties":    PRIMARY, IDX_AGENT_ID, IDX_ANI, fk_event_parties_events1, fk_event_parties_agent1, fk_event_parties_party_types1. Table "events": PRIMARY, IDX_G_CID, IDX_EVENT_TIME, fk_events_event_types, fk_events_cause_code1,    Tried to set my select with this "FROM demo_c2g_event_parties USE INDEX (PRIMARY)" but still the time to generate is actually 40 sec  :)

Comment: "using temporary" and "using filesort" are always taking time.

if you append 'ORDER BY NULL' may get "using temporary" and "using filesort" to disperser, and that could save some time, do IDX_AGENT_ID include only agent_id, or both agent_id and g_event_id, using the suggested alter table may change that row from "using where" to "using index".

more then that is hard to say without doing tests

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select 
ep.agent_id,
ep.g_event_id,
e.event_id,
e.event_time
from event_parties ep
join events e on e.g_event_id = ep.g_event_id
order by e.g_event_id DESC, e.event_time desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This gives me only one row even if i got more rows in event_parties (have edit my question above to be more specific).